# Transferring contents from one page to another in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a php script. What I have to do is to send contents from one page to another.

For example :

An employee applies for leave(from and to date). This leave details should be sent to his manager page for his approval (with from and to dates). If person 'A' is the manager and person 'B' is the employee then B's leave details should be sent only to person A page and not to all the managers. How to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create field supervisor in employee table and assign specific supervision id to each employee and use this id to display leave details on manager page

Comment: @Harry I am new to this and seriously I have no idea about this. can you please elaborate on what you said.

Comment: Take from ,to date into session or u can pass the value through the url...otherwise just create a database for this operation

Comment: Let me know how to get employee details for apply leave?

Comment: By entering your details in login form you will be redirected to the apply leave page where you can apply leave and these leave details will be stored in to employee database.

Comment: Each supervisor details enter in employee table as a employee.each employee as a supervisor so you can save supervisor id in supervisor column of each employee.In supervisor page you can fetch data of employee leave using his id like select * from leave where super_id=employee id

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is to create a link between person A and person B via the database. That way you can run a query for the manager that only pulls out the leave dates for employees that they have the relation with.

As the manager -> employee relationship could be many to many, it would make sense to have the leave table as the relation table between the two.

You would then be able to run the query to pull out all the leave requests for a particular manager

`SELECT * FROM employee_table
JOIN leave_table ON leave_table.employee_id = employee_table.id
JOIN manager_table on manager_table.id = leave_table.manager_id
WHERE manager_id = xxx`

Answer (score 1):

```
Make two Tables:

employee:
1.id
2.emp_name
3.emp_designation
4.manager

Leaves Table:

1.id
2.emp_id
3.from:
4.to



//While Login Make Session
$_SESSION['user'];
$_SESSION['emp_designation'];

//Check if the login user emp_designation is Manager
$query="select a.*,b.emp_id from leaves a left join employee b on a.emp_id=b.id where a.manager='".$_SESSION[user]."'";
```

Comment: Thank you Vikas. Lemme try this. will accept your answer after implementing it.